# Nginx rewrite location internally to serve static content

Tags: ubuntu, nginx, routing, static-routes, static-content

I'm trying to serve static content from an endpoint that differs in hierarchy structure than the actual root directory structure. This is the result I'm trying to achieve:

`0.0.0.0/Claw/scripts/main.js -> /home/ubuntu/Claw/public/scripts/main.js`

I'm using the following Nginx configuration:

```
location ~ ^/Claw/(images/|styles/|scripts/) {
    root /home/ubuntu/Claw/public;
    access_log off;
    expires max;
}
```

This is failing as `/home/ubuntu/Claw/public/Claw/scripts/main.js` doesn't exist. Therefore I need to remove the prefixed *Claw* from the location internally. How can I go about doing this?

I want this structure so I can host multiple Node apps from different endpoints on the same domain.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
location ~ ^/Claw/(?<subdir>images|styles|scripts)/(?<file>.*) {
    alias /home/ubuntu/Claw/public/$subdir/$file;
    access_log off;
    expires max;
}
```

It seems that nginx doesn't pass variables captured into numbered variables from `location` directive to inside the block. When the variables are given names, then they work.

Comment: I've added the working config - you were halfway there, thanks for your help :)

Comment: It could have also worked without the slashes in the end of the $subdir parts, because nginx appends the rest of the URI anyway after the `alias` directive. Good that it works now anyway.

Answer (score 0):

You could use `alias` directive for this.

```
location ~ ^/Claw/(images|styles|scripts)/ {
    alias /home/ubuntu/Claw/public/$1/;
    access_log off;
    expires max;
}
```

Comment: This isn't working: trying `/Claw/scripts/main.js` is resulting in `Claw/scripts/main.js/` and a 403 error.

Comment: Show full nginx config

Comment: Sure: http://pastebin.com/B6hUM6za

Comment: It should work http://nginx.org/r/alias. What's in nginx error log?

Comment: `2014/08/28 16:59:12 [error] 21128#0: *5 directory index of "/home/ubuntu/Etch/public/scripts/" is forbidden, client: 0.0.0.0, server: _, request: "GET /Etch/scripts/main.js/ HTTP/1.1", host: "0.0.0.0"`